Really being Buddhist does not require an act of faith?
For what is my understanding of Buddhism, the Buddha teachings aim to solve the problem of suffering. The buddha said you don't have to have faith in him or his teachings that you will be liberated from suffering, but you are encouraged to try it yourself and experiment the results. At the same time, you might need several lives to obtain liberation, isn't this equivalent to an act of faith? From the perspective of a person who is approaching Buddhism for the first time, you ask them to put a lot of effort and time on something it is not verifiable. Kinda like christianity, if you behave according to the christian commandments you will go to heaven, I feel like they are the same concept.
Also during my researches I have found in Buddhism teachings there are a lot of analogies that are quite charming, but if you think about it carefully they are not quite correct. The one I have met the most is the analogy between the Four noble Truth and a medical treatment. Regarding the treatment part in particular, I think a medical treatment is a very precise and deterministic series of steps. You follow the steps and you get a precise result in more or less precise period of time. The Noble Eightfold path instead, I find it very vague, a lot of concept are explained with "it can't be comprehended with concepts and logic". Doesn't this also require an act of faith?
To people who are practicing Buddhism, have you done an act of faith when you approached Buddhism for the first time?

Actually, the several lives or at most 7 lives in order to attain Enlightenment refers to a Sotapanna. There are 2 caveats to this 7 lives length. First, the person must attain stream-entry in this life. Second, I suspect why it took up to 7 lives is because the person chose to take it easy, perhaps?

The Noble eightfold path is not vague. Where are you conducting your research? Maybe you are getting wrong explanations from there. You can approach the Dhamma by studying it.

Being a Buddhist requires an act of faith because the claim that liberation from suffering, which is the main goal of Buddha's teachings, cannot be verified unless you try it yourself, which, however, means taking a profound, long-term, possibly life-lomg (or more) journey based on continuous practice and inner transformation. Now some people have argued that every action you do is an act of faith that you will get the desired result. I feel like it's a very stretched argument, but even if I would accept it as correct, everyday actions or small actions are validated from repeated everyday experiences and experiences of people around you. The "act of faith" you have to do is negligible compared to what is asked to a Buddhism practitioner. Furthermore, this can't be done with the concept of liberation, because liberated people are very rare and even if you meet one, you cannot tell if they are liberated or not.

The buddha said you don't have to have faith in him or his teachings that you will be liberated from suffering, but you are encouraged to try it yourself and experiment the results.
This is probably a paraphrase of the Kalama Sutta.
At the same time, you might need several lives to obtain liberation, isn't this equivalent to an act of faith?
... to obtain complete liberation.
There's the notion of "stages of enlightenment".
At the first level, someone might understand the doctrine, behave ethically and experience less suffering.
I think a medical treatment is a very precise and deterministic series of steps.
Perhaps so, for some treatments.
But for psychiatric treatment, for example, I think it's still trial and error and not so deterministic: try an obvious/standard treatment, and if that doesn't work then try something else.
The one analogy with medical treatment that I've heard of is the parable of the arrow.
Kinda like christianity, if you behave according to the christian commandments you will go to heaven, I feel like they are the same concept.
It's said that

The Dhamma is well declared by the Bhagavā: visible here and now, immediate, inviting to come and see, effective, to be individually ascertained by the wise.
Dhammānussati

It's not a question of waiting, it can be tested by experiment and experienced.
To people who are practicing Buddhism, have you done an act of faith when you approached Buddhism for the first time?
Yes and no.
To take your analogy, it's an act of faith on your part to accept the doctor's prescription. But it's the action of the medicine, not the faith, that's "effective".
Similarly I had some faith, but also some reason to believe, that Buddhist doctrine was worth learning better

It helps to recall that the dharma is a way of acting that eventually frees us from the influences of karma, and that karma is (in essence) a metaphysical process of cause and effect. In that sense, we have faith in the dharma in the same way we have faith in the laws of physics: practical experience leads us to the belief that it works.
The caution here is that we should not turn the Buddha or the dharma into an abstract, untethered ideal that we have faith in: i.e., some 'thing' that we worship. Worshipping the Buddha or the dharma is contrary to practice, in the same way that worshipping Newton's laws would have barred us from deeper understandings of physics. The dharma is a seed that unfolds in our lives; we have to work the soil and give it space to grow in its own way, otherwise it will never be anything more than an unfulfilled seed.

Faith in Buddhism is quite different from Christianity. My first encounter with Buddhism was reading the words, “life is suffering”. It resonated deep within. I just felt the author had it all summed up. It was only much later that I realized the 1st Noble Truth, dukkha, is much more than living a life; it is about existence. But the fact that it resonated meant faith and belief that the Buddha had a cure was ignited. (Strangely, there are those who think there is nothing wrong with dukkha, it is part of living and what makes life interesting and colourful. Perhaps, the door of the Dharma is not yet opened for them).
I am not a good student in Buddhism. A bright student would immediately see not just the truth in the 1st but also those behind the 2nd, 3rd and 4th Noble Truths and begin curing themselves. Most part of my life was spent inconsistently applying the treatment prescribed by the Buddha. I would forget to take the medicine and then when it hurts too much, go back to being an obedient patient....not a good patient to be honest.
But this winding on/off process allowed me to verify that the treatment works. We experience a lot of things in our life. It’s like picking up a stick. Often, we don’t know what is at the other end of the stick. As we go through life, tasting and accumulating experiences, we learn that we should pick up the right sticks (experiences) and avoid the wrong ones. Later, we learn to anticipate what is at the other end in order to choose the correct sticks. But even the right experiences eventually change. And when they change, I have seen myself and others do very unskillful things to try and hold back the changes but to no avail.
Ajahn Brahm once related a story as below.

Ajahn Chah picked up a stick by the side of the path and asked, “How heavy is this stick?” Before anyone answered, Ajahn Chah threw the stick into the bushes and said, “A stick is only heavy when you hold it. When you throw it away, the heaviness is gone.”.

I spent much of my adult life learning how to let go. Good, bad and so-so experiences, letting go of them turns out to be a skill; a very useful one. There are many types of letting go. A common type, forcefully, sometimes accompanied with tears flowing. Another is with anger, frustration and even hatred. Others come with bewilderment, confusion and uncertainty. Then, there is the rare type; with peace, acceptance and wisdom because that’s the way things are. The mind remains at ease with this type of letting go.
So, faith in Buddhism is nothing like that in monotheistic religions like Christianity. We have to do the verification on ourselves through our life and experiences. The doctor (the Buddha) can only prescribe the medicine; we are the ones that believe, swallow and confirm for ourselves that the medicine does relieve the pain and cure the ailments. As time passes, we find ourselves suffering less and our minds becoming more at ease and peaceful.

The "follower by faith" basically has faith in the Buddha as the teacher of the path to the end of suffering, the Dhamma (teachings of the Buddha) and the Sangha (the 8 types of individuals on the path). This faith will eventually drive him towards making progress on the path.
Just by faith alone, nothing will be attained because that is motivation without effort. Yet, no progress will be made without faith either, because there is no motivation as the prerequisite for effort.

And what person is a follower by faith? It’s a person who doesn’t have
direct meditative experience of the peaceful liberations that are
formless, transcending form. And having seen with wisdom, their
defilements have not come to an end. And they have a degree of faith
and love for the Realized One. And they have the following qualities:
the faculties of faith, energy, mindfulness, immersion, and wisdom.
Even the least of the noble ones possesses the five spiritual
faculties, which include absorption.This person is called a follower
by faith. I say that this mendicant also still has work to do with
diligence. Why is that? Thinking: ‘Hopefully this venerable will
frequent appropriate lodgings, associate with good friends, and
control their faculties. Then they might realize the supreme
culmination of the spiritual path in this very life, and live having
achieved with their own insight the goal for which gentlemen rightly
go forth from the lay life to homelessness.’ Seeing this fruit of
diligence for this mendicant, I say that they still have work to do
with diligence.
MN 70

Eventually they may become "freed by faith". Not totally liberated, but they have made significant progress on the path.

And what person is freed by faith? It’s a person who doesn’t have
direct meditative experience of the peaceful liberations that are
formless, transcending form. Nevertheless, having seen with wisdom,
some of their defilements have come to an end. And their faith is
settled, rooted, and planted in the Realized One. This person is
called freed by faith. I say that this mendicant also still has work
to do with diligence. Why is that? Thinking: ‘Hopefully this venerable
will frequent appropriate lodgings, associate with good friends, and
control their faculties. Then they might realize the supreme
culmination of the spiritual path in this very life, and live having
achieved with their own insight the goal for which gentlemen rightly
go forth from the lay life to homelessness.’ Seeing this fruit of
diligence for this mendicant, I say that they still have work to do
with diligence.
MN 70


When Buddha said Sabbe Sankhara Anicca , all conditioned phenomena are impermanent ,you do not go on verifying whether every Sankhara is impermanent or not. When Buddha said practice compassion to such an extent that if somebody cuts off your limbs , you should not have any cruel thoughts for him or her , you do not go on verifying what happens if you start having cruel thoughts for him or her.
You have to have faith in Dhamma. Although it is verifiably true you must believe in Buddha and his teachings to quickly reach the Nibbana. Doubt in the teachings in one of the fetters which prevent reaching Nibbana. Faith accelerates the spiritual process.
As far as medical analogy is concerned , you should remember that medicine can not help you escape suffering permanently. The Noble 8 fold path can. Nobel Eight fold path is very precise if you are serious.
Most people do not have the guts to follow the Path precisely.

You must to have faith (conviction) in him or his teachings if you will be liberated from suffering. You are encouraged to try it yourself and experiment the results. But there will be no results without faith because if you have no faith you will not even try it.
There is no teaching of the Buddha about several lives to obtain liberation.
The Noble Eightfold Path is not vague. All of the concepts explained can be comprehended with concepts and logic. But, yes, this also requires an act of faith.
All people who are practicing Buddhism have done an act of faith when they approached Buddhism for the first time.
When you walk down the street, you do so with an act of faith your legs will work & not collapse from underneath you. Whenever you eat food, you do so with an act of faith the food is not poisoned.
Every volitional act, whether wholesome or unwholesome, is performed with faith.

When you walk down the street, or eat food, you see people doing that everyday, and you have done that a lot in your life, can you really call it an act of faith? At the same time how many people do you know who have been liberated? You can't even evaluate if a person has been liberated or not i think. I don't think we can put the two things on the same level. Maybe I'm too fussy but those are the analogies I'm talking about.

Sorry but its an act of faith. If your knee has a tendency to dislocate then you will understand what it means to lack faith in your legs
